# A web-based team time and task manager

Tags: time-management, task-management

I'm looking for a task manager to measure time spent on tasks.

Hard Requirements

- Define clients
- Define Projects (assigned to client)
- Task creation and time tracking per task. Tasks will be done via multiple sessions.
- Task needs to have three stages (Inprogress/Done/Invoiced)
- Can be kanbaan
- Asssign employee to selected projects
- Allow client to see tasks (readonly) and how much time was spent on what

Soft requirements:

- Self hosted (pref docker)
- OpenSource

The ideal workflow I want is simple. Client comes with task, task (for example a script) will be done in multiple sessions.
I assign a worker (sometimes freelancer) to do task. He/she will mark their times.
On this basis I will bill client ( and pay my freelancer if it was done by fr).

Client can see time so he can monitor his spendings and say "Hey, stop, new features are getting out of budget".

It must be easy to manage. I tried Harvest, but whole idea with walking around callendar is so much time consuming. Simple task with time tracker would do best.
It can track sessions on callendar for internal use of who was doing what and when. But If client says "bill me" i want to go to his project, mark tasks that are done and get amount to bill.
No invoicing needed.

Maybe someone has seen something that will have these options?